# How to compare Map with List

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, contains

Sorry for the title, I couldn't find a better one and I know it sounds confusing.
The issue is as follow:

I have a HashMap with that Looks like the following:

```
Map<String, ClassA> myMap;
```

Also, I have a List that Looks like the following:

```
List<ClassB> myList;
```

The ClassB looks like the following:

```
   public class ClassB{

    //many things

    private String someString;
    //getter
    //setter
    }
}
```

The someString is the key string `myMap`

I want to remove from the map, all the objects that I can't find in the list `myList` with the least number of iterations, because this cleaning will happen once every few seconds all the time for life.

Any algorithm? Pattern or even example?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to iterate `List<ClassB> myList` at least once in order to do so, but you can do it with one iteration exactly, which makes it ideal algorithmic-wise.

Create a new Map and for each element in the list check if it's in `myMap` and if it's there - add it to the new Map you created. After you finish iterating the list simply assign: `myMap = newMap;` and you're done.

Note: this is ideal for minimal number of steps, but it *is* using more memory than an "in-place" algorithm.

Comment: Hi i alfasin thank you for the help, it sounds good except the fact that i need to use less memory and less cpu time.
actually what i did was to iterate over the list and do the change to the map without copying to another map.
what I'm looking for here is to improve the code

Comment: @MarwanJaber you should check both options and avoid any "optimizations" unless needed. Keep in mind that by "copying" the map you are actually copying only pointers to the objects and *not* the objects themselves, so unless you have a *lot* of objects such an "optimization" is not necessary!

Comment: @MarwanJaber  It's difficult (sometimes, impossible) to have both: use less memory AND use less cpu. You need to choose one.

Answer (score 2):

With java 8 stream API,

```
Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<>(myMap.keySet());
myList.forEach(entry -> keySet.remove(entry.getSomeString()));
keySet.forEach(key -> myMap.remove(key));
```

That's it. What I just did was just removed the keys which are in the list from the `keySet`. Then, I remove all the keys which are left. This will run in `O(n)`.

This will be consuming lesser memory than the current solution since you are creating an additional `Set` instead of a `Map`.

Comment: The check `!myList.contains(key)` takes `O(n)` steps and repeating it `n` times makes it `O(n^2)` which is not ideal since the OP explicitly asked for something efficient since it will happen every few seconds.

Comment: Hi Imesha, Than you for the help it looks a good one, do you know if it is better than iterating with the list and searching the map each time?

Comment: Yup, I fixed it. Thanks for all the comments. Now I have optimized it to run in O(n).

Comment: As I see, it's correct now. What's wrong with it as you suggest?

Comment: `myList` contains `ClassB`, not `String`. Also, your solution takes a full 2 iterations. Also, you can do `myMap::remove` instead of `key -> myMap.remove(key)`. Also, you can call `keySet.forEach()` without `stream()`. Alternatively, you can just do `myMap.keySet().removeAll(keySet);`. Also, `keySet` is not a very descriptive name for keys you want to remove.

Comment: I see. I had missed that someString part. Apart from that others are not affecting the performance except the fact that I'm using two iterations. As I need lesser memory than the accepted answer, it is a trade off between memory and reducing an iteration

Comment: Your solution takes more memory, since it copies the entire key set, rather than just the required entries.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want `retainAll`. The trick is that you call this on the map's `keySet()`, which has the side effect of removing unwanted entries from the map.

Next, you want to retain the elements not in the `List<ClassB>`, but in a list of strings derived from each instance of `ClassB`. You can use a stream to do that.

```
    myMap.keySet()
         .retainAll(myList.stream()
                          .map(ClassB::getSomeString)
                          .collect(toList()));
```